# ROR Devise "Email can't be blank" Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am following a tutorial to setup a prelaunch page using Devise to manage collecting user emails. when  I enter an email address i get error message     "1 error prohibited this user from being saved:Email can't be blank"
My users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
rolify
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

after_create :add_user_to_mailchimp
before_destroy :remove_user_from_mailchimp

# override Devise method
# no password is required when the account is created; validate password   when the user sets one
validates_confirmation_of :password
def password_required?
if !persisted?
  !(password != "")
else
  !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
end
end

# override Devise method
def confirmation_required?
false
end

# override Devise method
def active_for_authentication?
confirmed? || confirmation_period_valid?
end

def send_reset_password_instructions
if self.confirmed?
  super
else
  errors.add :base, "You must receive an invitation before you set your password."
end
end

# new function to set the password
def attempt_set_password(params)
p = {}
p[:password] = params[:password]
p[:password_confirmation] = params[:password_confirmation]
update_attributes(p)
end

# new function to determine whether a password has been set
def has_no_password?
self.encrypted_password.blank?
end

# new function to provide access to protected method pending_any_confirmation
def only_if_unconfirmed
pending_any_confirmation {yield}
end
```

my users controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
@users = User.all
 end

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
else
  redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
end
end

def destroy
authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an  administrator.'
user = User.find(params[:id])
unless user == current_user
  user.destroy
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
else
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
end
end
```

Devise/Registrations/new view

```
<div class="email-capture">
<%=form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>  registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :class=>"email"%>
<%= f.submit " ", :class=>"reg-btn"%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Log message after i click submit

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-02 10:36:11 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"mytoken", "user"=> {"email"=>"test@email.com"},
"commit"=>" "}
←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  rollback transaction
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you modified your registration form?

Make sure that the email input has `name="user[email]"`

When you submit your registration form, what do you see in the server log for `params`?

Also, the users_controller shown should be for admins only -- make sure you aren't accidentally routing registrations to it.

UPDATE:

This is a wild guess, but I notice you are getting a DB rollback. Is it possible that you have a database restriction that requires password to not be NULL, for example?

Comment: I did modify the registrations form. I updated the question to show the registrations view and the server log message after i hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), might be strong parameters issue, try to add something like following lines in your application_controller.rb:

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```